# help me for add input in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery, jquery-effects

i have tow input, style column and mediumCell. i want first input only have add, not add and remove together.
also each input except first input have remove link and last input have add and remove together.

code: http://jsfiddle.net/cJACG/15/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:

```
$(function () {
            $('a.add_input').live('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var newDiv = $('.ai_service').find('div:first').clone();
                newDiv.append('<a href="" class="remove_input">remove</a>')
                newDiv.find('input').each(function () { $(this).val(''); });
                $('div.ai_service:first div:last').before(newDiv);
            });

            $('a.remove_input').live('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).closest('div').remove();
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign a empty value to the cloned input:

```
var input = $column.clone().val('').wrap("<div />").parent().html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cloning and appending, you can insert and remove nodes before or after siblings:

```
 $('a.add_input').click(function() {
        $('a.remove_input').before('<input type="text" name="service[]" style="width: 155px;" placeholder="خدمات دیگر" title="خدمات دیگر" />');
    });
```

A simplified version of your code can then be written [thus](http://jsfiddle.net/cJACG/14/).